# Multiplying two large vector variables

Tags: c++, vector

The following code is to find the **Maximum Pairwise Product** (MPP) which is:

> You're given an array of N integers and a number K. The maximum
> K-product of the array is the maximum product of any K length subsequence of the array. For example, the maximum 2-product of the array
> **[-5, 3, 4, -6]** is **30** because the product of the subsequence **[-5, -6]**
> is **30** and it is impossible to achieve a larger subsequence products.

The code below calculates the **MPP** for every input except for "`90000 and 100000`" which must give an output **9,000,000,000**, but I got **410065408**:

```
int MaxPairwiseProduct(const vector<int>& numbers) {
    int result = 0;
    int n = numbers.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (numbers[i] * numbers[j] > result && numbers[i] * numbers[j] % 2 == 0) {
                result = numbers[i] * numbers[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Sadly, these pages ([1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-a-pair-with-maximum-product-in-array-of-integers/) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950568/python-for-maximum-pairwise-product)) did not help me with my request.

Comment: What value has `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` on your system?

Comment: I did not use this method

Comment: I am suggesting that an `int` on your system may not be able to store the value 9,000,000,000.

Comment: BTW, You can have better algorithm. result is the maximum between the product of the 2 biggest numbers or the 2 lowest.

Comment: @Jarod42 the 2 lowest??

Comment: @tobi303: for negatives numbers: `{-100, -10, 6, 7}`

Comment: @Jarod42 still getting time limit exceeded

Comment: Can you show your new resulting code ? (better in a new question as not really related to this question).

Comment: Use biginteger for C++

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you multiply your integer, it is outgoing of the `int` type boundaries. In this case, use the `long long` type:

```
long long MaxPairwiseProduct(const vector< long long >& numbers) {
long long result = 0;
int n = numbers.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
        if (numbers[i] * numbers[j] > result && numbers[i] * numbers[j] % 2 == 0) {
            result = numbers[i] * numbers[j];
        }
    }
}
return result;
```

Please note that if your numbers are too big (bigger than 2^63-1) you can not use standard C++ types. There is all type boundaries [C++ data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx).

Comment: Those "C++ data types" are what Microsoft's 2015 compiler does. That does not mean that every compiler will do that. C++ allows a much larger set of possible ranges.

Comment: **long long** does not help! I used **long long int** and worked well for me

Comment: [`long long` and `long long int` are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18971763) (potentially with the exception if you use a non-standard compiler, or a compiler with really weird behavior that treats the two as different types. It's not supposed to)